# How do I sequentially execute wsl commands from java?

Tags: java, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to execute `wsl` commands from `java`.

I'm trying to do this using `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`.

As I understand, there are two ways to do this:

1. Run `wsl` along with command as argument (for example: `wsl ls -l`) (do this per-command).
2. Run `wsl`, and then execute the commands one by one.

But there are some problems with `1` and `2`.

**With point `1`:**

1. When the command terminates, the process does not stop. So even if i run `wsl ls`, I can not determine the moment when I can call next command.
2. `wsl` does not save the state between such calls, so it's not very convenient

**With point `2`:**

Since `wsl` does not show `bash prompt`, I can not track when the command stopped displaying information. For example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wsl");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
osw.write("ls\n");
osw.flush();
```

And all I can read is:

```
build.gradle
gradle
gradlew
gradlew.bat
out
settings.gradle
src
```

No `selya@selya-pc:/mnt/c/Users/selya$` read. So I can't use it as a separator between commands. I think that `wsl` somehow tracks, in what environment it was launched, for example, through `isatty()`, and therefore the output is different.

**With both:**

Аs far as I know, for programs that are running outside the terminal, `stdout` is not buffered. So there are some problems with, for example, `sudo`, because it asks fro a password without `newline`/`flush` (`[sudo] password for selya:`), therefore I can't read this line...

I found a solution - pass command as argument to `unbuffer` util, for example:

```
wsl unbuffer -p sudo apt-get update
```

(`-p` stands for `pipeline`).

But other problems still remain. Is there any way to do this? Or maybe there is lib for it? Even `c` or `c++` lib will suit my needs...

P.S. I tried to find a solution for several days. Russian-speaking SO didn't help me, that's why I'm here. Sorry for my English...

Comment: There seems to be several questions here: 1. Why is there no output when running `wsl` from Java, 2. Why does `wsl ls` not show a bash prompt, 3. How do I determine when a wsl command exits?, 4. How do I separate output from multiple sequential shell commands in the same bash shell? 5. How do I run wsl commands programmatically from C++?    StackOverflow works better if you ask a single question per post. Can you edit your post and ask a single question that will help you do what you want? (For example: "How do I run a wsl command with sudo and provide a password programmatically?")

Comment: Have you considered adding your own separator with e.g. `ls; echo "__END__"` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with the help of [pty4j](https://github.com/traff/pty4j). It works on linux, mac and windows. (It works like pseudo terminal on linux, but have nice java interface).

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on/specify what you did with the help of pty4j to start up and execute multiple commands in WSL `<version>` sequentially? Or even present a Minimal Working Example (MWE)? Either would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use point 2 (run `wsl` and then pipe commands to process.outputWriter() for the STDIN) with [Baeldung's tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java) with no issues.  The big gotchas:

1. That output stream flush() call prevents a hang
2. With the tutorial you are started in the Windows Home directory, not the linux home directory.
3. You need to write `exit\n` to prevent a hang

I haven't needed to run SUDO yet though.